# XNA 3D object is view as Correctly

Tags: xna-4.0

My code for view 3D object Card is View as like this image. Please check this URL:
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/zKVd6Pnv0xzRcG5QdVpGSFnWbYDqyrC4vyF2n264NDE=w359-h207-p-no
https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/ZAsvunwH18MpfGcYSCH7RY0DXhNZgZBrDXLLZIfw_U8=w316-h207-p-no

```
Vector3 cameraPosition = new Vector3(0.0f, 15.0f, -5.0f);
float aspectRatio = graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.AspectRatio; 

foreach (ModelMesh mesh in myModel.Meshes)
  {
    foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
      {
        effect.World = Matrix.Identity;  
        effect.View = Matrix.CreateLookAt(cameraPosition,Vector3.Zero, Vector3.Up); 
        effect.Projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.PiOver4, aspectRatio,
                                1.0f, 8000.0f);
      }
    mesh.Draw();
 }
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: And how it should be?

Comment: https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-pVBJsxvGT1E/VKd2Usd_SKI/AAAAAAAAAVk/F0fPrBvM48w/w389-h161-no/New.PNG

Comment: Want the shape like above image. The width of the card is like single card. Not like object is expanded.

Comment: I think problem not in how you draw it, but in mesh you trying to draw. Are you imported card from some 3D editor?

Comment: yes. How to do it then? Please tell me how to do it. I am using fbx object from maya.

Comment: I myself a beginner and have never worked in Maya, only in Blender and 3DMax, and uses the format .obj and .xmd because they are easier. For such a simple model of the card playing, you could create a mesh directly in the code, or use instead of .obj .fbx. Content Pipeline for .obj exists as an example, for .xmd I wrote my own. However if only Maya and only .fbx I'm could not help.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Let me check. If you have any reference how I can use the .obj and .xmd format object. Please share it.